# Testing if a number is a Palindrome using different functions (C++)

Tags: c++, function, palindrome

The code I am using is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int reverse (int number){
  int t = number, m = 0;
    do
    {
        m = m*10 + t%10;
    } while(t /= 10);

    return m == number;
}

bool isPalindrom(int number){
    bool Palindrom = reverse(number);
  if(Palindrom == true){
   return true;   
  } else { 
   return false;   
  }
    return 0; 
}

int main()
{
  int number;
  cout << "Please input a number " << endl;
  cin >> number;

  if(isPalindrom){
   cout << "This is a Palindrom" << endl;   
  } else {
    cout << "This is not a Palindrom" << endl;   
  }

}
```

The issue I am having is that isPalindrom is always evaluating to true. I believe it is because I am trying to set this up incorrectly. The program asks us to use the two functions bool isPalindrom(int number) and int reverse(int number). I'm just learning to use functions in C++ so i'm not to sure what I should do. Should I have reverse return the numbers flipped self (m) then in palindrom compare number to m and if it evaluates to true, it will return true. Then in the main check with an if statement to see if isPalindrom is true/false.

Comment: `if (Palindrom == true) return true; else return false;` is so-called [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). You want `return Palindrom;`. In fact, the rest of the function is *worse*: `return 0;` at the end of it makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Functions should do what they say. Reverse should reverse its argument, and isPalindrome should check if its argument is a palindrome. Currently reverse does both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the function correctly.

```
 if(isPalindrom){
    cout << "This is a Palindrom" << endl;   
 } else {
    cout << "This is not a Palindrom" << endl;   
 }
```

To call it you have to supply a parameter like this

```
if (isPalindrom(number)) {
    ....
```

In your code `isPlanindrom` is (I believe, but actually it does not matter if I am right on this point) a function pointer and because it is in the condition of if it gets converted to a bool, which is `true` always.

PS: I just noticed that I was too fast in writing the answer. I just saw this one problem and didnt look at the rest of the code. It seems like you need to learn about very basics which would be too much to cover here in an answer. My suggestion: Get a book and rtfm :P

Comment: Ah this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `main`, you are evaluating the existence of a function called `isPalindrom`; you aren't actually calling the function. `if(isPalindrom){` should become `if(isPalindrom(number)){`.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to call `isPalindrom` with an argument. Here's the fix:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool reverse (int number){
    int t = number, m = 0;
    do
    {
        m = m*10 + t%10;
    } while(t /= 10);

    return m == number;
}

bool isPalindrom(int number){
    return reverse(number);
}

int main()
{
  int number;
  cout << "Please input a number " << endl;
  cin >> number;

  if(isPalindrom(number)){
   cout << "This is a Palindrom" << endl;   
  } else {
    cout << "This is not a Palindrom" << endl;   
  }
}
```

I've also:

- simplified your `isPalindrom()` function to a simple return statement;
- set the return of `reverse` from `int` to `bool`.

You can try a <kbd>[LiveDemo](http://cpp.sh/8kp5)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you forgot to *call* `isPalindrom`.

Long answer: `isPalindom` decays to a nonnull function pointer, and nonnull pointers test true, this you always see the the `if` branch taken.

---

Also:

- Yes, judging both by the name and the return type, `reverse` is intended to return the reverse of a number.
- And correspondingly, it is the job of `isPalindom` to do the actual comparisons.

Furthermore, in most cases,

```
if (boolean) { return true; }
else { return false; }
```

should be replaced with

```
return boolean;
```

Finally, you really ought to be testing whether or not `cin` succeeded and your input is valid. (e.g. is the user allowed to enter `0`? `-73`? `Zero`?)

Comment: Oh right I didn't think about if they inputed something like this. Thanks. (Edit::) I do believe though that 0 is a palindrome and it will evaluate to true. As for the negative or a string, I will have to fix those.